# nginx not serving default mediagoblin on debian jessie

Tags: nginx, debian, debian-jessie

I have been trying to figure this out all weekend now... I have given up on googling. I have found similar issues but none of the solutions I find have resolved the issue. I'm very new to media goblin, and haven't really dived into linux this deep before, so I am very noobish.

I have followed the instructions from http://mediagoblin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/siteadmin/deploying.html keeping all the defaults, just to get the default setup to work. I figured from there I would be able to start changing things and see what happens. Okay enough of the intro.

When I input

```
    nginx -t
```

I get

```
    nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

When I input

```
    ./lazyserver.sh --server-name=fcgi fcgi_host=127.0.0.1 fcgi_port=26543
```

I get

```
    Using paster config: paste_local.ini
    Using ./bin/paster
    + export CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=true
    + ./bin/paster serve paste_local.ini --server-name=fcgi fcgi_host=127.0.0.1 fcgi_port=26543 --reload
    Starting subprocess with file monitor
    2017-05-22 08:39:22,377 INFO    [mediagoblin.app] GNU MediaGoblin 0.9.0 main server starting
    2017-05-22 08:39:22,647 INFO    [mediagoblin.app] Setting up plugins.
    2017-05-22 08:39:22,648 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.plugins] Importing plugin module: mediagoblin.plugins.geolocation
    2017-05-22 08:39:22,648 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.plugins] Importing plugin module: mediagoblin.plugins.basic_auth
    2017-05-22 08:39:22,648 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.plugins] Importing plugin module: mediagoblin.plugins.processing_info
    2017-05-22 08:39:22,648 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.plugins] Importing plugin module: mediagoblin.media_types.image
    2017-05-22 08:39:22,797 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.celery] Setting celery configuration from object "mediagoblin.init.celery.dummy_settings_module"
    Starting server in PID 990.
```

It doesn't appear as though the server is being served. When I go to the server ip i get the default nginx page.

my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file is as follows

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    events {
            worker_connections 768;
            # multi_accept on;
    }
    http {
            ##
            # Basic Settings
            ##
            sendfile on;
            tcp_nopush on;
            tcp_nodelay on;
            keepalive_timeout 65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;
            # server_tokens off;
            # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
            # server_name_in_redirect off;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type application/octet-stream;
            ##
            # SSL Settings
            ##
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            ##
            # Logging Settings
            ##
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
            ##
            # Gzip Settings
            ##
            gzip on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";
            # gzip_vary on;
            # gzip_proxied any;
            # gzip_comp_level 6;
            # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
            # gzip_http_version 1.1;
            # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
            ##
            # Virtual Host Configs
            ##
            include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
            include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf is as follows

```
    server {
     #################################################
     # Stock useful config options, but ignore them :)
     #################################################
     include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
     autoindex off;
     default_type  application/octet-stream;
     sendfile on;
     # Gzip
     gzip on;
     gzip_min_length 1024;
     gzip_buffers 4 32k;
     gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
     #####################################
     # Mounting MediaGoblin stuff
     # This is the section you should read
     #####################################

     # Change this to update the upload size limit for your users
     client_max_body_size 8m;

     # prevent attacks (someone uploading a .txt file that the browser
     # interprets as an HTML file, etc.)
     add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

     server_name mediagoblin.example.org www.mediagoblin.example.org;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/mediagoblin.example.access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/mediagoblin.example.error.log;

     # MediaGoblin's stock static files: CSS, JS, etc.
     location /mgoblin_static/ {
        alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin/static/;
     }

     # Instance specific media:
     location /mgoblin_media/ {
        alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/media/public/;
     }

     # Theme static files (usually symlinked in)
     location /theme_static/ {
        alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/theme_static/;
     }

     # Plugin static files (usually symlinked in)
     location /plugin_static/ {
        alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/plugin_static/;
     }

     # Mounting MediaGoblin itself via FastCGI.
     location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:26543;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        # our understanding vs nginx's handling of script_name vs
        # path_info don't match :)
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";
     }
    }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit 1

Response from running

```
    ./lazyserver.sh --server-name=fcgi fcgi_host=127.0.0.1 fcgi_port=26543
```

is still

```
    Using paster config: paste_local.ini
    Using ./bin/paster
    + export CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=true
    + ./bin/paster serve paste_local.ini --server-name=fcgi fcgi_host=127.0.0.1 fcgi_port=26543 --reload
    Starting subprocess with file monitor
    2017-05-22 12:06:37,345 INFO    [mediagoblin.app] GNU MediaGoblin 0.9.0 main server starting
    2017-05-22 12:06:37,583 INFO    [mediagoblin.app] Setting up plugins.
    2017-05-22 12:06:37,584 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.plugins] Importing plugin module: mediagoblin.plugins.geolocation
    2017-05-22 12:06:37,584 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.plugins] Importing plugin module: mediagoblin.plugins.basic_auth
    2017-05-22 12:06:37,584 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.plugins] Importing plugin module: mediagoblin.plugins.processing_info
    2017-05-22 12:06:37,585 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.plugins] Importing plugin module: mediagoblin.media_types.image
    2017-05-22 12:06:37,714 INFO    [mediagoblin.init.celery] Setting celery configuration from object "mediagoblin.init.celery.dummy_settings_module"
    Starting server in PID 976.
```

current mediagoblin nginx.conf:

```
     server {
     #################################################
     # Stock useful config options, but ignore them :)
     #################################################
     include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

     autoindex off;
     default_type  application/octet-stream;
     sendfile on;

     # Gzip
     gzip on;
     gzip_min_length 1024;
     gzip_buffers 4 32k;
     gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;

        listen       80;
        server_name  10.1.1.74;


     #####################################
     # Mounting MediaGoblin stuff
     # This is the section you should read
     #####################################

     # Change this to update the upload size limit for your users
     client_max_body_size 8m;

     # prevent attacks (someone uploading a .txt file that the browser
     # interprets as an HTML file, etc.)
     add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

     server_name mediagoblin.example.org www.mediagoblin.example.org;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/mediagoblin.example.access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/mediagoblin.example.error.log;

     # MediaGoblin's stock static files: CSS, JS, etc.
     location /mgoblin_static/ {
        alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin/static/;
     }

     # Instance specific media:
     location /mgoblin_media/ {
        alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/media/public/;
     }

     # Theme static files (usually symlinked in)
     location /theme_static/ {
        alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/theme_static/;
     }

     # Plugin static files (usually symlinked in)
     location /plugin_static/ {
        alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/plugin_static/;
     }

     # Mounting MediaGoblin itself via FastCGI.
     location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:26543;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        # our understanding vs nginx's handling of script_name vs
        # path_info don't match :)
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";
     }
    }
```

current /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

---

Edit 2
Current nginx.conf file for server (both defaults are working)

```
 server {
 #################################################
 # Stock useful config options, but ignore them :)
 #################################################
 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

 autoindex off;
 default_type  application/octet-stream;
 sendfile on;

 # Gzip
 gzip on;
 gzip_min_length 1024;
 gzip_buffers 4 32k;
 gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;

    listen       80;
    server_name  10.0.0.192;


 #####################################
 # Mounting MediaGoblin stuff
 # This is the section you should read
 #####################################

 # Change this to update the upload size limit for your users
 client_max_body_size 8m;

 # prevent attacks (someone uploading a .txt file that the browser
 # interprets as an HTML file, etc.)
 add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

 server_name mediagoblin.example.org www.mediagoblin.example.org;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/mediagoblin.example.access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/mediagoblin.example.error.log;

 # MediaGoblin's stock static files: CSS, JS, etc.
 location /mgoblin_static/ {
    alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin/static/;
 }

 # Instance specific media:
 location /mgoblin_media/ {
    alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/media/public/;
 }

 # Theme static files (usually symlinked in)
 location /theme_static/ {
    alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/theme_static/;
 }

 # Plugin static files (usually symlinked in)
 location /plugin_static/ {
    alias /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/user_dev/plugin_static/;
 }

 # Mounting MediaGoblin itself via FastCGI.
 location / {
    fastcgi_pass 10.0.0.192:26543;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    # our understanding vs nginx's handling of script_name vs
    # path_info don't match :)
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";
 }
}
```

When I run this command, as suggested by the guide, I am unable to load the page.

```
    ./lazyserver.sh --server-name=fcgi fcgi_host=127.0.0.1 fcgi_port=26543
```

However when I run this command, it works.

```
    ./lazyserver.sh --server-name=fcgi fcgi_host=10.0.0.192 fcgi_port=26543
```

I'm not sure if the first one, as supplemented by the guide, implied that you were accessing it locally... which would make sense since the dns url created in the directions was supposed to work without implicitly creating a dns entry anywhere... orrr if i'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: You have an error in your configuration file. You now have two `server_name` directives You didn't need to edit this file if you removed default file. But now, you should test your nginx configuration with `nginx -t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a default server in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. If you use `mediagoblin.example.org` to access the server, then your server configuration will match.

You state that you use the server's IP address, which means that the default server will be used instead.

You have a number of options:

1. You could add the IP address to the `server_name` directive and pretend that that is a valid name for your server.
2. You could set up DNS or hosts so that you can use the correct name.
3. You could remove the other configuration file, so that this configuration becomes the de-facto default server.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: Would I delete the default site then and modify the new config file that is in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf... This file points to a config file that rests withing the mediagoblin directory

Comment: Would you be able to show me exactly what I would need to change in order to get the site running with the mediagoblin nginx config file.

Comment: Do you have a file called `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` which may be a symbolic link to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`? That file is causing the default nginx page that you are seeing. If you remove `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` then your configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf` (which is also a symlink - but that is not important) should begin to work **after you restart `nginx`**.

Comment: Hi there. I rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default and /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. I then edit the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf as shown in the edited post, however I am still getting the same error. Is there any other information I can provide to assist?

Comment: I edit it again. Thanks for all your help btw. It is up and running based on edit two. however i'm not entirely sure why it is working if I change the ip address in the lazyserver command. It seems like the whole set of instructions was intended to be tested locally, and if that is the case, it would make sense why I couldn't get it to work at first. I'm running without a gui, so testing came from another vm.